# Calculating the percentage change by year for a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
data = {'Year': ['2010', '2011', '2012'],
        'Total_Population': [1000, 1200, 1600]}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_sample.head()
```

I want to calculate the percentage change in `Year` for `Total_Population`. I tried following this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776327/how-to-calculate-the-percentage-of-change-based-on-previous-years-where-the-firs). Which boiled down to this code

```
cols1 = ['Year', 'Total_Population']
vals = df[cols1].merge(df.assign(year=df['Year']+1), on=cols1, how='left')['values']
df['change_in_population'] = df['values'].sub(vals).div(vals).mul(100).fillna(0)
```

For the actual .csv file the size is about 215.2 MB and when I try the latter my memory blows up and I have 64 gb of RAM. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips like how to write a good title and starting with your own research. If you just google "pandas percentage change", you get useful results, like the docs for example: [`DataFrame.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html)?

```
df_sample['% change'] = df_sample['Total_Population'].pct_change() * 100
print(df_sample)
```

Output:

```
   Year  Total_Population   % change
0  2010              1000        NaN
1  2011              1200  20.000000
2  2012              1600  33.333333
```

Comment: Does the data have to be in order?

Comment: @Wolfy, yes the data has to be sorted by year..